# Something about all UI work must be done on the main thread in swift?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, parse-platform

I am learning to use Swift to communicate with Parse. And I found some doubts here. 
The following is two segmentations of codes in which I use Parse to find associated user and its avatar. The first one works well but I figured I supposed to put all UI work on the main thread, so I change it to the second one. Now, I'm wondering if there's something incorrect about doing it this way?

```
findSweeter.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
    if error == nil {
        let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
        cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

        let profileImage:PFFile = user["profileImage"] as PFFile
        profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!)->Void in

            if error == nil {
                let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                cell.profileImageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}


findSweeter.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser

        let profileImage:PFFile = user["profileImage"]? as PFFile
        profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            if error == nil {
                let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username
                    cell.profileImageView.image = image
                })

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first idea was fine.  Its true that you must manipulate UI on the main thread, but the completion blocks *are* executed on the main thread.  The work that's being done off the main is the network request.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I realized that for findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock, the completion block is executed on the main thread. (All Parse completion blocks should execute on the main thread.)